# How does the $p$-group fixed point theorem proof make sense?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group acting on a finite set $X$, and ${\rm Fix}_G(X)$ the subset of $X$ consisting of fixed points under this action. Then
$$|X| \equiv | {\rm Fix}_G(X)| \pmod{p}.$$

The proof of this consists of saying $X$ is a disjoint union of orbits that all have a cardinality equal to $p^y$ where $y$ is an integer.

But surely this isn't true?

Using the $\Bbb Z_4$ group as an example, let $X = \{ 0,2,3\}$. There is one orbit here of length $4$, but $X$ does not have the element '$1$' in it, so it cannot be called a disjoint union of that orbit.

Comment: How does $\mathbb Z/4$ act on $X$?

Comment: “Equal to $1$” is incorrect; the statement is that the *size* of the orbits is a power of $p$ (including $1$).

Comment: Whichever action you mean, how is an action on a 3-element set going to have a 4-element orbit?

Comment: @RaviFernando: Addition.

Comment: @Thorgott: I suppose it would be a 3-element orbit. But then, X is still not a disjoint union of orbits which have cardinality p^x, surely?

Comment: There can’t be a $3$-element orbit. Addition is not a group action, precisely because you removed $1$ and so $0$ can’t be sent to anything anymore.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan But it's a group action on the set of the group. Does X have to be a subgroup? Can it be bigger? Smaller? The proof seems unintuitive to me.

Comment: To the people who downvoted: this person is asking a well-posed question, there is a clear flaw in their logic that we have the opportunity to correct, it's clearly not an attempt at getting a solution to their homework, so why the downvote?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem and its proof? That is the reason why you can tell the orbits have order a power of $p$. Running that theorem’s proof through your attempted counterexample would highlight why what you are attempting does not work.

Comment: Regarding your reply to Qiaochu: What does “the set of the group” mean? No, $X$ does not have to be a subgroup, or even a subset of the group. It can be any set provided you explicitly define an appropriate action. You do know what the requirements of an action are, right? Otherwise, that’s where we need to start.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be assuming that if $G$ acts on a set $X$ and $Y$ is a subset of $X$, then the action restricts to an action of $G$ on $Y$. This is not the case in general; to make this work you need the hypothesis that $Y$ is what we call $G$-invariant, which means $g\in G$ and $y\in Y$ implies $gy\in Y$.

In the example you've given the set $\{0,2,3\}$ is not a $\mathbb Z_4$-invariant subset of $\{0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Could you finish the last line off by saying 'therefore you can't [do X thing]'? Am I not able to do a group action with that set? What qualities mean you can do a group action?

Comment: @Piomicron A group action (of $G$ on $X$) is a function $G \times X \to X$ that satisfies a few axioms.  If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to define the action by $(g, x) \mapsto g + x \mod 4$.  This isn't a group action because it isn't a function from $G \times X$ to $X$; namely, some group elements send some set elements to 1, which isn't in $X$.

Comment: @Piomicron first and foremost the thing you need for a group action is, for every pair of "inputs" $g\in G$ and $x\in X$, an "output" $g\cdot x\in X$ (or you can state this in the way Ravi says above, we need a function $G\times X\to X$). For instance in your post you say the action should be "addition", but if you take $g=1$ and $x=0$ then what should the output $g\cdot x$ be? It should probably be $1$ but this is not in your set $X$.

Comment: @Piomicron to add to this, you could do SOME group action on that set, just not THIS group action; you could have a group action where $g\cdot x=x$ for all $g\in G$ and $x\in X$ (this works no matter what $G$, $X$ are). So it's just that THIS group action doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexMathers So, could you do g⋅x=2x mod 7? In which case, couldn't you have an orbit of 7 no matter what the actual elements of G are?

Comment: @Piomicron this won't satisfy the property $(gg')x=g(g'x)$ of group actions